# Coarsest $\sigma$-field of $\mathbb E(X\mid Y)$

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory, conditional-probability, expectation

I was reading up on Conditional expectation and Sigma field and saw this statement which I dun really understand.

The coarsest $\sigma$-field for which $\mathbb E(X\mid Y)$ is a random variable is the $\sigma$-field generated by the $Y$ that is denoted by by $\sigma(Y)$

I don't really understand this statement. Need some explanation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\mathbb E(X\mid Y)$ is in particular, by definition, a real valued random variable which is $\sigma(Y)$-measurable.

Without further restrictions, we cannot assert that it is measurable with respect to a strictly smaller $\sigma$-algebra (for example take $Y=X$).

Comment: the smallest $\sigma$-field is $\sigma$(Y), it can't be any smaller. am i right to say this?

Comment: In general yes, but for example when $X$ is constant, it _may_ be a smaller one.

Comment: "for example when X is constant, it may be a smaller one." can explain this further?

Comment: In this case, $\mathbb E(X,\mid Y)$ is constant (equal to $\mathbb E(X)$), hence it is also measurable with respect to $\{\emptyset,\Omega\}$.

Comment: meaning to say that X and Y are independent?

Comment: Each constant random variable is independent of any other one, but here the computation can be carried elementarily.